# Можно ли еще оптимизировать запрос (group by)

Tags: sql, база-данных, запрос

Имеется таблица с 10 полями (среди которых `id` - уникальный идентификатор, и поле `Field1` в котором значения **повторяются**).

Нужно сделать выборку (со всеми полями в каждой записи), в которой `Field1` будет уникальным (условие выбора уникального значения `Field1` – не важно).

Я придумал:

```
select * 
from MAIN_TABLE 
where ID in (
    select min(id) 
    from MAIN_TABLE 
    group by «Field1») %s  
order by DATE_END_VIEW
```

где `%s` – дополнительные параметры выбора (в Delphi – строка с форматированием)

Можно ли запрос написать более кратко?

Comment: Более краткий запрос не значит более хороший. Какую цель Вы преследуете стараясь сделать запрос более кратким?

Comment: Если СУБД позволяет, обычно используют функции ранжирования (http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_ranking_functions.html), что даст ответ за один проход таблицы.

Comment: У вас в примере хоть и написано `min(id)`, но нигде про это не сказано. Если вам не нужна первая такая запись, то можно убрать `WHERE ID IN (...)`, вынеся `group by «Field1»`, т.е. как-то так: `select * from MAIN_TABLE WHERE %s  group by «Field1» order by DATE_END_VIEW`. Но тогда вы не сможете контролировать какую именно запись выбрать из записей с одним и тем же `Field1`. Т.е. если понадобится, например, выбрать первую (или последнюю), то придется вернуться к текущей версии.

Comment: @BOPOH написанный Вами запрос `select * from MAIN_TABLE WHERE %s group by «Field1» order by DATE_END_VIEW` не будет работать. При группировке придется каждый столбик обернуть в функцию типа `max`, но тогда никто не гарантирует, что все данные в результате будут взяты из одной и той же строки таблицы. Кажется, что та конструкция которая есть вполне себе хороша и не надо ничего нового изобретать

Comment: С чего это работать не будет? Если нет разницы какую именно запись с одним и тем же Field1 брать, то все нормально: группировка вернет первую встретившуюся запись, а не будет ползать по другим записям с тем же Field1, собирая из них данные. Если же есть разница какую запись надо выбрать, тогда да - надо использовать текущий вариант (про что я в комменте и написал). Т.е. ничего оборачивать в `max` не надо

Comment: @BOPOH Пожалуйста, составьте из ваших комментариев один ответ.

Comment: Я попытался в  "IBExpert" выполнить запрос предложенный @BOPOH с одной вставкой, а именно:

`select * from MAIN_TABLE where RIGHT_INPUT <> -100 group by Field1 order by DATE_END_VIEW`  

но у меня почему-то летит ошибка:   

"Invalid token.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Invalid expression in the select list (not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause)."

Comment: @Konstantin78, блин... Я про mysql писал (с другими можно считать не работал). Раньше там в `GROUP BY` надо было указывать все поля из `select'а`. В вашем случае это тоже походу надо сделать. В mysql сейчас такой проблемы нет

Comment: :-) а,, да я совсем забыл почему я отказался от GROUP BY, не хотел запрос наводнять всеми полями. это громоздко получается... (и его каждый раз нужно переделывать, когда новое поле в таблицу добавляется).  А насчет SQL, я же специально метку "sql" поставил.  **значит будем пользоваться первоначальным запросом**... Просто он как-то **подтормаживает**

Answer (score 1):

> Можно ли запрос написать более кратко?

Это неверная постановка вопроса. Написать кратко не означает быстро и тем более правильно.

Скорость работы запроса будет зависеть от наличия отсутствия индексов, связей и проч. SQL'ной халабуды.

Чтобы разобраться в этом обычно принято использовать нечто типа:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN //для Oracle
EXPLAIN //mysql
EXECUTION PLAN //SQL Server
```

который выдает как будет работать ваш запрос. Вы увидите где у вас потенциальные тормоза и проч. тонкости. В зависимости от коих вы дальше сможете проиндексировать нужные поля или решите перестроить ваш запрос.

Comment: Небольшое дополнение: по `mysql` на днях статейку [про профилирование запросов](http://debian-help.ru/web-servers/mysql-indexes-explain-profiling/) нашел, новичкам полезно было бы почитать.